# Is there a way to find Epic Games game data (game name, ID, genre, developer/publisher, etc) in a similar way that there is for SteamWebAPI?

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing a CS project for school to take the game data from multiple (random) games from different APIs, and I don't get credit for using prebuilt python packages to manage my code. I need to get user/game general data from the Epic Games API, but from what I have found I'm unsure of how to make a request to any interface to get this data without using a prebuilt package (which I cannot do). I plan on using the requests module in python to send the get request, and will then handle the data myself, but I am unsure of what interface within the api to use. Any help would be greatly appreciated

I have looked on the documentation for the EOS API on the Epic Games documentation page, but cannot find anywhere to send a request that returns game data.

When working with steam and the steamAPI I used the steamCMD api to collect my data (example of the request I use there: https://api.steamcmd.net/v1/info/%appid%)

Comment: This might be a helpful source of information on how to do what you are trying to: https://github.com/SD4RK/epicstore_api/ . It's unclear where they are getting the information from, but it sounds like it may have been from reverse-engineering the Epic games client's communications. It also looks like it uses a GraphQL interface, but I was able to make some REST calls from my browser. You should be able to follow this link:  https://store-content.ak.epicgames.com/api/content/productmapping and it should return a product mapping. If you can do more with that I don't know.